# Display Model's Data in NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, nsmenuitem

I'd like to display some data of my model within a status bar menu. So, I bound my entity-object to the title of an `NSMenuItem`:

```
        [self.statusMenu setAutoenablesItems:NO];

        NSMenuItem * exportMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
        [exportMenuItem bind:@"title" toObject:expo withKeyPath:@"menuItemTitle" options:nil];
        [exportMenuItem setEnabled:NO];

        [self.statusMenu insertItem:exportMenuItem atIndex:3];
```

It works fine so far from init. But when I update my Model it does not updates the title of the `NSMenuItem`.

Comment: It's impossible to say why your menu item title isn't updating without knowing more about the object `expo`. Is it KVO-compliant for the key `menuItemTitle`? How is the value for `menuItemTitle` being updated? (You might also want to use `NSTitleBinding` instead of `@"title"`.)

Comment: @ipmcc Hey, due to your answer I guess the reason. `menuItemTitle`isn't a real property. It's just a method that combines different properties of expo to a single string. (accepted `NSTitleBinding`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the canonical solution to this issue is to implement a class method like this:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingMenuItemTitle
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects: @"propertyMenuItemTitleDependsOn1", 
                                  @"propertyMenuItemTitleDependsOn2",
                                  nil];
}
```

If you implement a method like this, then the framework will handle calling `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` for the key `menuItemTitle` any time any of the other properties are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it:

`menuItemTitle` is a dynamic getter method which combines two actual properties of `expo`. So the reason for `NSMenuItem`'s title to not get updated is probably, that `menuItemTitle` probably never gets actually set.

So how do I tell, that `menuItemTitle` was changed, when one of my properties was set? 
Overriding `expo`'s setters to add `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"menuItemTitle"];` and `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"menuItemTitle"];` does not work as it causes an endless loop in calling the setter itself again and again.

So here is my solution: I overrode `[NSManagedObject setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key]`:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"menuItemTitle"];
    [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"menuItemTitle"];
}
```